# how to get rid of visual tab focus

Tags: linux, qt, focus

while running my qt application in linux, a tab focus appears on the selected

control- like this:

[image]

that doesn't happened in windows.

how can i get rid from this visual focus?

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

- Explicitly set the `QApplication` **style** to one that doesn't draw a focus rectangle on the tabs, for example **plastique**. This might break any custom style sheets. The native look and feel will be gone, too.
- Set the `QTabWidget` or `QTabBar` **focusPolicy** property to **NoFocus**. The user won't be able to change between tabs using the keyboard.
- Set the `QTabWidget` **documentMode** property to **true**.